# What is best practice for font-end NPM package file structure?

Tags: javascript, npm, package

I am making an NPM package for the front-end and I want to know what the best file structure to use is.  I have one `code.js` file and will have one `code.min.js` file.  Should I have these two files in the root directory? In a `dist` folder? In a `src` folder?  What is the best practice for this file structure - specifically on the front-end?

Answer (score 0):

you should separate your source from your development compiled files, as much as possible.

For example on my projects, all minificated files, should be in a dist folder. The non minificated files, are not getting on the server. You wouldn't want a customer to accidentally use a non-min css and get 0.2 sec for extra load, would you? :)

Also, I do strongly recommend you to google this:  "recommended structure [add framework name here]"

Answer (score 0):

`code.min.js` is certainly the minified version of `code.js`. You simply need to add `code.min.js` to your project. 
For node projects, you can insert directly the  cdn link into your code or when you create a file ( js, css or image), it goes to the public folder.

[image]